# How can I adjust an account, cart, etc pages in spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

**I do not want to use layout.** I am happy with the default but I just want to make minor changes. 
I can't seem to find this answer, besides doing layouts. I would like to use `deface` and insert before/after particular divs.

Suppose I want to change the user account page, how can I do this with `deface`? 
 I am okay with using this `virtual_path => "spree/layouts/spree_application"` as well, but it doesn't see `id=content`. Everything appears to be the same as before. No changes.

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/shared/<WHAT IS OVER HERE to USER ACCOUNT?>',
                     :name => 'something',
                     :insert_after => 'div#content',
                     :text => '<div class="div that I want to change/add/mod">whatever</div>'
)
```

Comment: I'm not clear on the problem you're having, exactly. Which page are you tried to override?

Comment: the user account page

Comment: Ok. And the issue is you're not sure what path you should use for the `virtual_path` option?

Comment: Yes, that would be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you're not sure where a particular template lies, head over to the [Spree Github page](https://github.com/spree/spree), and look under the `app/views/` directory in either  *backend*, *frontend*, *api*, or wherever is relevant.

So in your case, you probably want to *deface* the [users/edit page](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/backend/app/views/spree/admin/users/edit.html.erb). From that link, you can see the virtual path that you will need to put in the Deface options, so it would look like this:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/admin/users/edit',
                     :name => 'something_meaningful',
                     :insert_after => 'div#some_selector',
                     :text => '<div class="div that I want to change/add/mod">whatever</div>'
)
```

Two things to note:

1. There's no `div` with id "content" in that view, so you'll have to examine the source code in the github repo to find out where the content you want to change is located
2. When looking at the Spree github repo, **make sure you're viewing the branch that corresponds to the version you're using**. As an example, I'm presently using Spree 2.3, but there is a considerable amount that changed between that version and the current one, with templates potentially being moved or deleted altogether.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought I was suppose to only go to the shared folder. And yes, I see what you are saying about the folders.

Comment: @JamAndJammies Pretty much any view can be overwritten with Deface, including those coming from other gems and extensions too, so long as you know the correct path.